# manera correcta de hacer una caja de texto en mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

tengo mi caja de texto de tipo int en mi la vista mi sale asi con las flechas arriba y abajo, como le declaro para que no me aparesca asi, o como puedo poner un dropndownlist con los años ahi.

[image: flechas]

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gestion, "Gestión")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gestion)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gestion)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El editor por defecto para una propiedad de tipo `int` es un `input` de tipo numérico.

El cómo se muestra (con flechas o sin ellas) es cuestión del navegador.

Si quieres utilizar un editor diferente debes indicarlo expresamente. Por ejemplo si, como comentas, quieres hacer un desplegable para seleccionar un año podrías hacer algo así:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gestion, "Gestión")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.Gestion, Enumerable.Range(1950, 100).Select(x=> new SelectListItem {Text= x.ToString()}))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gestion)
</div>
```

Esto mostraría un desplegable con 100 valores a partir de 1950.

Comment: muy bueno, tu que eres experto en este trabajo, aqui me paso algo similar,    https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111905/como-llenar-un-dropdownlist-en-mvc-c