# ¿Como llenar un DropDownList en mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

En mis parametros tengo "Opcion" que son

```
-Gestion
-Colegio
-Estado
-Pais
```

quiero cargarlo en mi DropDownList 
intente de esta manera cargarla pero no es como llevarla a la vista, tienen algun otro metodo ?

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {    
List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();

lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Gestion", Value = "1" });
lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Colegio", Value = "2" });
lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Estado", Value = "3" });
lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Pais", Value = "4" });

 ViewBag.Opciones = lst;

        return View();
}
```

mi vista:

```html
@model TNT.Controllers.ResumenParam

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Imprimir", "Resumen", new { id = "PDF" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gestion, Enumerable.Range(2000, 20).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gestion)
        </div>
       
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Opcion", ViewBag.Opciones)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Modelo:

```
public class CampoResumenColegioParam
{

    //     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una Gestion")]
    //     [Display(Name = "Gestio")]
    //  [DataType(DataType.int)]
    public int Gestion { get; set; }
    public int Opciones { get; set; }
}
```

[image: mi error]

Comment: y como has intentado cargar esos datos en tu DropDownList ?

Comment: Revisa este workshop sobre ASP.net MVC, te dará un buen inicio al framework: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos

Comment: Hola amigo, revisa este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727386/dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-with-razor esta detallado de como implementar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta guardando los `SelectListItem` en un `ViewBag` y luego le pasas los datos al helper `DropDownList`.

En tu action tendrias esto:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();

    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Gestion", Value = "1" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Colegio", Value = "2" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Estado", Value = "3" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Pais", Value = "4" });

   ViewBag.Opciones= lst;

  return View();
}
```

En tu vista entonces para mostrarlo seria esto:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Opciones, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Opciones)
```

Comment: estas cerca me salio este error: 
Mensaje de error del compilador: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TNT.Controllers.Reportes.ResumenParam>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: editatada esta.

Comment: aun sigue con el mismo error que la imagen.

Comment: sale el mismo error que el de la imagen    https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xh0Y.png

Comment: tambien funciona de esta manera  `@Html.DropDownList("Opciones", null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es crear una enumeración con los posibles valores:

```
public enum ValoresOpcion
{
    Gestion= 1, Colegio = 2, Estado = 3, Pais = 4
}
```

La propiedad de tu modelo podría ser del tipo de la enumeración:

```
public class Modelo
{
    public ValoresOpcion Opcion { get; set; }
}
```

Y en la vista podrías utilizar el método de extensión `EnumDropDownListFor':

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model=> model.Opcion)
```

Comment: edite mi pregunta